# sylius: after doing composer update on sylius 0.16 i get 'Unrecognized option "classes" under "sylius_product"

Tags: php, symfony, bundle, sylius

Please Help

I was installing LexikTranslationBundle via composer on sylius 0.16.
 after a composer.phar update I get this:

> [Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]
>       Unrecognized option "classes" under "sylius_product"
>
> Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception
>
> [RuntimeException]
>         An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command:

How to correct this issue?

Comment: Thanks in advance. this is the answers. Look to sylius yaml config file and change the content according to :https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/cd46a90b9ebcbe96c5dc30711c0f4e9de11d6be5/src/Sylius/Bundle/CoreBundle/Resources/config/app/sylius.yml#L123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer is found here. change your config sylius.yaml according to this :
https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/cd46a90b9ebcbe96c5dc30711c0f4e9de11d6be5/src/Sylius/Bundle/CoreBundle/Resources/config/app/sylius.yml#L123

Next when you are looking somthing concerning sylius always pay attention to the date of the post.